# Display healthService data such as step in AmbientMode (Android wear)

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os, watch

I want to display health-service data such as step, pace, etc in AmbientMode.

But HealthServices(using ExerciseClient https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/health-services/active) seems to go into Sleep state when entering ambient mode.

I tried using AmbientUpdate with AlarmManager, but HealthServices did not wake up. Please let me know if you have a good way to solve this problem.

I want to change the data of the screen in the middle in AmbientMode.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the relevant code that shows how you are setting up the connection to HealthServices. It will make it easier for people to help you. In the meantime, here are some suggestions for you to look into:

1. ExerciseClient will only send you data when you have an active workout with a [listener set](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/health-services/active#updates). It sounds like you do get updates in interactive mode so I'm going to assume that this part is working for you. Make sure that you don't accidentally end your workout e.g. in onPause or some other life cycle method/function that is called when the app loses focus (this happens when the device enters ambient mode).
2. Make sure that you have a Foreground service set up as outlined in the [spec](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/health-services/active#structure), and that you have the required permissions. Otherwise, you might run into issues when the device enters ambient mode and your app is sent to the background.

> Use a continuously-running ForegroundService in conjunction with ExerciseClient to ensure correct operation for the entire workout.
>
> Using a ForegroundService is essential when requesting location data. Your manifest file must specify foregroundServiceType="location and specify the appropriate permissions.
>
> Note: If your app experiences AUTO_ENDED_PERMISSION_LOST errors, this is likely caused by a missing ForegroundService with appropriate location permissions.

3. Worth noting is that when the device is in ambient mode you will get data less frequently. HealthServices will do more batching of data in order to minimize the impact on battery life. The frequency and batch size varies based on the type of metric you are requesting. Make sure that you allow enough time for data to come through, and that you are parsing the batched data points correctly.
4. Make sure that you give enough time for the ExerciseClient to flush all data points when you end your workout or you might lose data.

Finally, if you're not actually tracking a workout, you might be better off using the [PassiveMonitoringClient](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/health-services/passive#receive-data).

> To receive data updates in the background, use the PassiveMonitoringClient. Your app must have a BroadcastReceiver declared in its AndroidManifest.xml. When you register to receive updates from Health Services, they will be delivered to this receiver.

Comment: Thanks for your replay and sorry my comment too late.
Health-service is sleep when ambient mode and can't wake up the service. but samsung health service is available to wake up using core wake-up when ambient mode.

My project use health-service not samsung health-service, then i can't display health-service data such as step, pace, etc in AmbientMode.